# What is be easiest way to write a web app that can also be run standalone on windows and linux

Tags: web-applications, cross-platform

I would like to write a *simple* app, but would like to have it on web, I do not want to complicate the maintenance and stuff. So the best what I can think of, is an app, that is web based, and it's somehow included into a standalone app that can be runned on windows and linux.

For mobile phones, I would use for example PhoneGap, to achieve my goal.

Thanks.
Filip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), you can [embed](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty) it into your application.

Comment: Thanks - I will checkk that out !

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you don't need anything for a **simple** web app. As long as you don't make any XHR requests you don't even need to have a server. Inline everything and just produce a HTML file with all of your JavaScript, CSS and data included.

This results in a single file app that can be started by double clicking the html file.

Comment: Okay - maybe 'simple' was not the word i wanted to use.